# find corresponding value from other dataframe row and columns location

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a master file which has other data frame name (df2, df3), row and columns index which use to populate the master file x column

I think to use the for loop but don't know how to start and I haven't used R for a while.

```
master <- data.frame(df = c("df2","df2","df3"), column =c("A","C","B"),row = c(1,2,3), x = c(1,1,1))


df2 <- data.frame(A = c(2,4,6), B = c(1,3,5),C = c(4,8,5))

df3 <- data.frame(A = c(12,14,16), B = c(11,13,15),C = c(24,28,25))
```

Thanks

Comment: Please consider format your question for better understanding. For example you can put the codes in codes highlight block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use for-loop, I guess the following could help you

```
for (k in 1:nrow(master)) {
  master$x[k] <- eval(parse(text = sprintf("%s$%s[%s]",master$df[k],master$column[k],master$row[k])))
}
```

where `eval` and `parse` can evaluate your query as string